# Packery not arranging additional divs when loaded via AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, packery

I am using [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) to arrange blog posts in a masonry format. This works fine for posts that are initially displayed on the page but when I load new posts - when the pagination links are clicked - via AJAX the posts just get added to the container but do no 'repack' or re-arrange in a masonry format.

I am using WordPress and using my own AJAX call, see code below:

```
// For jQuery noConflict
(function($)    {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Find out the page number
        var pageNumber;
        $('.custom-pagination a.page-numbers').click(function() {
            pageNumber = $(this).html();
        });

        // AJAX call to load more posts when pagination links are clicked
        $(document).on( 'click', '.custom-pagination a.page-numbers', function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            page = pageNumber;
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    action: 'ajax_pagination',
                    query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
                    page: page
                },
                success: function( html ) {

                    var $container = $('#all-posts').packery();

                    $container.append( html );
                    $container.packery( 'appended', html );

                }
            });
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
// End jQuery noConflict
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to call packery again to re-arrange my posts in a masonry format after they are loaded via AJAX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and took care of it server-side (web2py/python), in accordance with [the instructions here](http://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html):

```
# this function is called via ajax
def function_that_loads_the_new_content():
   ...
   new_divs = #generate new content
   new_divs_as_string = ''.join([str(x) for x in new_divs])
   # this script runs when the new content is appended to the container
   update_results = \
       "var $items = $('%s');$pack.append($items).packery( 'appended', $items );" \
        % new_divs_as_string
   return update_results
```

The idea is to use packery's appending functionality after the new elements have been added to the container element. The above script is essentially equivalent to this template offered in the packery page:

```
$('.append-button').on( 'click', function() {
  // create new item elements
  var $items = $('<div class="grid-item">...</div>');
  // append items to grid
  $grid.append( $items )
    // add and lay out newly appended items
    .packery( 'appended', $items );
});
```